# How to reset form which is not rendered at the moment - How to reset it the right way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, conditional-rendering

I try to realise a upload page as part of a project. It's working fine but I wonder if there is a better way to reset my v-form for my inputs.

**So here is what I do:**

```
   <v-container v-if="!success">
            <v-flex>
                <v-card>
                    <v-form ref="form" class="pa-5">
                        <v-select
                            ...
                        >
                        </v-select>
                        <v-select
                            ...
                        >
                        </v-select>
                        <v-text-field
                            ...
                        />           
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <v-file-input
                                ...
                            ></v-file-input>
                        </form>
                    </v-form>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-btn @click="addDocument">Add document</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-container>
        <v-container v-if="success">
            <v-flex>
                <v-card>
                    <v-alert v-if="notification.show" :type="notification.type" class="pa-3">
                        {{notification.text}}
                    </v-alert>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-btn @click="resetPage">Okay</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-container>
```

Two v-containers which will either be rendered if *success* is true or not. If *success* is false all the required inputs will be rendered and if its true (for me this means the upload was successfull) the second v-container should be rendered.
The second v-container shows just a message about the success and a "Okay" button which calls the *resetPage* function. 
This function should reset all validations and clear all inputs.

**What I've tried:**

At first I tried this:

```
resetPage() {
                this.success = false;
                this.$refs.form.reset()
            }
```

which obviously doesn't work because $refs.from is not rendered because its part of the first v-container.

So I thought I have to call the reset after it's been rendered.

So I tried this:

```
methods: {
   resetPage() {
                   this.success = false;
               }
},
updated() {
   this.$refs.form.reset();
}
```

But quickly I learned that updated() is called if a input field changes or in my case one of the selects. I should have thought about this.

So I added *allowReset* and ended up with this:

```
methods: {
   resetPage() {
                   this.success = false;
                   this.allowReset = true;
               }
},
updated() {
   if(this.allowReset) {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
      this.allowReset = false;
   }
}
```

Its working like I need it to. But as I said updated() gets called everytime I select something or choose a file etc.

Is there maybe a better way to reach my goal?

Thank you in advance for all tips and tricks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `v-model` to your `v-form`. Whenever you reset the page by using `this.success = false`, the form should reset by itself.
When adding a v-model to a form it checks all of the `rules` set for the elements inside of that form. If they all pass the checks, the `formValid` will be `true`, otherwise `false`

simple example:

```html
    <div v-if="!success">
      <v-form v-model="formValid">
        <v-text-field v-model="a" :rules="[required]"></v-text-field>
      </v-form>
      <!-- Button will stay disabled as long as the form is invalid -->
      <v-btn :disabled="!formValid">Save</v-btn>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Success
    </div>
```

And in your data:

```js
    formValid: false,
    required: (v) => !!v || "Required" // Will print required if textfield is empty
```